# XSLT transform of XML document to XHTML document

Tags: xslt, text

Here's my template:

```
<xsl:template name="rec">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <div class="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="data-{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
      <xsl:call-template name="rec" />
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Given a document like so:

```
<test>
  <item value="1">Item 1 Text</item>
  <item value="2">Item 2 Text</item>
</test>
```

The above transform will turn it into:

```
<div class="test">
  <div class="item" data-value="1">Item 1 Text</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="2">Item 2 Text</div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having, is that this transform doesn't respect text nodes properly, and I don't have enough background with XSLT to figure out how to fix it. Here's the problem: given xml like so:

```
<para>This is a <emphasis>paragraph</emphasis> people!</para>
```

I would like to see the following output:

```
<div class="para">This is a <div class="emphasis">paragraph</div> people!</div>
```

The problem is that I'm not getting this - I'm getting this:

```
<div class="para">This is a <div class="emphasis">paragraph</div></div>
```

Notice the missing 'people!' text node. How can I fix my XSLT above to provide me with the output I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that

```
  <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
```

just selects the value of the *first* child text node, and outputs it.

The easiest way to do this right is probably to use `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead of `<xsl:call-template>`.

Then instead of

```
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
```

and

```
  <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
```

you can use

```
  <xsl:apply-templates />
```

which will apply the appropriate template to each child element and text node, in order, not skipping any.

Here is a complete implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">

   <xsl:template match="*">
      <div class="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="data-{local-name()}">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </div>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, which operates on all children of the context node, including text nodes, by default in absence of an explicit `select` attribute.

A default template is used for text nodes. This template simply copies them to the output.

Sample input:

```
<test>
   <item value="1">Item 1 Text</item>
   <item value="2">Item 2 Text</item>
   <para>This is a <emphasis>paragraph</emphasis> people!</para>
</test>
```

produces the desired output:

```
<div class="test">
   <div class="item" data-value="1">Item 1 Text</div>
   <div class="item" data-value="2">Item 2 Text</div>
   <div class="para">This is a <div class="emphasis">paragraph</div> people!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I see what you're doing here. =) This does indeed produce the effect I'm looking for - thank you very much!